# TFormatSettings.Create('en-US') returns different settings on different platforms

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Is it normal that `TFormatSettings.Create('en-US')` returns with `ShortDateFormat = 'm/d/yy'` on **Android** but returns with  `ShortDateFormat = 'M/d/yyyy'` on **Windows** ? Is it a bug?  I was thinking that the settings must be consistent against platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TFormatSetting` uses **platform-specific settings** whenever possible, even when using the same locale across platforms.

On all platforms, `TFormatSettings.Create(LocaleName)` converts the `LocalName` to a platform-specific `TLocaleID` and then calls `TFormatSettings.Create(LocaleID)`.

On Windows, the `LocaleName` is converted to a `TLocaleID` (alas for `LCID`) via `LocaleNameToLCID()` on Vista and later, and `EnumSystemLocales()` on earlier versions. The `LCID` for `'en-US'` is 1033.  `'m/d/yy'` is the RTL's default if the Win32 API `GetLocaleInfo()` function does not return a `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE` string for the specified `LocaleID`.  On your system, Windows is returning `'M/d/yyyy'` for LCID 1033, so the RTL's default is not used.

On Android, the underlying localization library used by the RTL is the cross-platform ICU library, so the `LocalName` is converted to a `TLocaleID` by simply encoding it as UTF-8 and then using that as-is. `'m/d/y'` is the RTL's default if ICU does not return a `UDAT_SHORT` string for the specified `LocaleID`.  On your system, ICU is returning `'m/d/yy'` for `'en-US'`, so the RTL's default is not used.